# how to find important factors in support vector machine

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm

The original data are large, so I cannot post it here.
The question is that I use the package e1071 in R to do the support vector machine analysis.
The original data have 100 factors and the prediction results is 1 or 0.
for example, I generate a random data frame with 10 factors.

```
for (i in 1:10){
    factor<-c(factor,runif(10,5,10))
}
value<-matrix(factor,nrow=10)
y<-sample(0:1,10,replace=T)
data<-as.data.frame(cbind(y,value))
```

I did the prediction pard, but I wonder how to determine which factors (among the 10 factors) are important (more related) to the results.

For example, The result might be factor 2,4,5, and 10 are contribute to the final results.

Can you help me with this?
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A complete answer to this question is not simple. Here is an example for getting started on this subject:

```
library(rpart)
library(e1071)

cat('Regression tree case:\n')
fit1 <- rpart(Species ~ ., data=iris)
print(fit1$variable.importance)

cat('SVM model case:\n')
fit2 <- svm(Species ~ ., data = iris)
w <- t(fit2$coefs) %*% fit2$SV                 # weight vectors
w <- apply(w, 2, function(v){sqrt(sum(v^2))})  # weight
w <- sort(w, decreasing = T)
print(w)
```

Result of script above is:

```
Regression tree case:
 Petal.Width Petal.Length Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width 
    88.96940     81.34496     54.09606     36.01309 

SVM model case:
Petal.Length  Petal.Width Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width 
   12.160093    11.737364     6.623965     4.722632
```

You can see the result variable importance of two models are similar.

This is one of many methods of interpreting SVM results.

See following paper for more information: "An Introduction to Variable and Feature Selection", http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/v3/guyon03a.html

Comment: I like the answer, however, it will imho suffer in case of un-normalized data.

Comment: Thank you so much. It helps a lot.